# Clear daterangepicker while user clear input textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using daterangepicker of bootstrap with `singleDatePicker: true`.

I have implemented it like below:

```js
$('#from_date').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    autoUpdateInput : false,
    locale: {
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    },         
});
```

When user clear the input textbox (here `from_date`) I need to clear the date selection in date modal.

Is there any way so that when user clear the textbox and focus out then date selection is cleared?

Comment: When I review http://www.daterangepicker.com/ I do not see this as an option. If it was jQuery UI, I would advise setting the `defaultDate` option to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#from_date').on('focusout', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).val(''); 
       //rest of the process or any function call backs goes here
    }
});
```

try this!